# KeyBindings command is not firing inside DataGrid cell

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, key-bindings

I'm trying to use a KeyBinding mechanism to fire an action when I'm inside DataGrid cell.

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="{Binding MainWindowKeyBindings.DatabaseGridKeyBindings.EscCommand}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

This is working only when I'm focusing my datagrid, but when I'm inside a specific cell, it's just not firing. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
<KeyBinding Key="Esc" Command="{BindingMainWindowKeyBindings.DatabaseGridKeyBindings.EscCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGrid}, Path=CurrentCell}"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Do you know maybe, why with the same logic, `Up/Down` arrows are not firing my command ? I just changed `Key="Esc"` to `Key="Up"` / `Key="Down"`, and it doesnt work with it.